# insert/ delete sections in cells UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, delete-row

Good afternoon,

I am trying to create expandable/ collapsible cells in a UICollectionViewController. The cells expand and collapse correctly. However, the information each cell holds stays present on the screen in the background. I will show pictures to explain. I am trying to delete the information from the view if the user collapses the cell, and insert it back if the user expands that cell.

The images below express the process of the cell starting in a collapsed state, expanding that cell, them collapsing that cell again. (note: this happens to every cell not just the first cell I clicked.

the first image is when the view loads and the cells are in the original collapsed state.

[image: collapsed state]

this second image shows when the user taps on the cell to expand it.

[image: expanded cell]

the third image shows when the user tries to collapse the cell.

[image: collapsing that cell again]

the code that I use to expand and collapse the cells are below

```
fileprivate let cellId = "cellId"
fileprivate let headerId = "headerId"
fileprivate let profID = "profID"
private let headerIdentifier = "userProfileHeader"
private let sectionIdentifier = "sectionHeader"
var section:Int?
var expandSection = [Bool]()
var items = [String]()

    fileprivate func setupCollectionView() {
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    self.expandSection = [Bool](repeating: false, count: self.items.count)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(userProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)

    collectionView.register(sectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: sectionIdentifier)
}

    fileprivate func registerCollectionView() {

collectionView.register(profCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "profCell")
    self.collectionView.register(userProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)

     self.collectionView.register(sectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: sectionIdentifier)
}



var headerView: userProfileHeader?
var sectionView: sectionHeader?

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
         let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? userProfileHeader

        if let user = self.user {
                 headerView?.myUser = user
             } else if let userToLoad = self.userToLoad {
                 headerView?.myUser  = userToLoad
             }

        return headerView!
    } else {

        let sectionViews = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: sectionIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? sectionHeader
        let categories = ["Skills, Preferences", "Bio", "Reviews"]
        sectionViews!.headerLabel.text = categories[indexPath.section]
        sectionViews!.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return sectionViews!
    }

}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: 340)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.expandSection[indexPath.row] = !self.expandSection[indexPath.row]
    self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!)
}

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "profCell", for: indexPath) as! profCell

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        cell.educationView.text = user.education
        cell.skillsView.text = user.skills
        cell.preferencesView.text = "wassup bitches"

    } else if indexPath.row == 1  {

        cell.bioLabel.text = user.bio

    } else if indexPath.row == 2  {

        cell.labels.text = "Reviews"

    }
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if self.expandSection[indexPath.row] {
        return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 300)
    }else{
        return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 80)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to insert and remove items inside `sizeForItemAt()`, call `reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet)` for the sections that get expanded or contracted. Then implement `numberOfItems(inSection section: Int)` to return 0 when contracted or items.count when expanded. Use sections to hold the top level items and cells to hold the collapsible sub-items.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not too familiar with collectionView Cells and the methods you have mentioned, could you possibly provide brief example code? this makes the sections disappear instead of the cells inside of the sections.

Comment: You might want to start with a tutorial like the one at: https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: This will cover the setup and custom cells. It doesn't cover headers though. You'll want your top level categories ('Skills and Preferences', 'Bio', 'Reviews') to display as section headers you create in the UICollectionViewDataSource method: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView

Comment: Thank you for this, I already have that method being called to use a custom header, would it be possible for me to have different sectionHeaders? I have updated my question

Comment: Is there a way where I could have multiple sections with different sizes and functions?

Comment: Yes, the header views are reused, so, in 'viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind()', you'll want something like headerView.label.text = categories[indexPath.section] where categories is your data array (like categories=["Skills and Preferences", "Bio", "Reviews"]) and label is the UILabel in your headerView that displays the category. If you want different headers for each section, you can use headers with different reuseIdentifiers or classes.

Comment: I have fully added all of my code that has to do with my collectionView. My apologies if there is a lot to digest. When I add this, my sectionViews view is blank.  Is there something That I am missing?